# Jest test fails if React component has any json import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Jest test case fails if react has any json import

Importing json files result in SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()

```
> 19 | import jsonfile from "./jsonfile.json";
     | ^
  20 | at Runtime._loadModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1216:39)
       at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:5:1)
       at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:3:1)
```

Jest transformation - similar to create-react-app

```
"transform": {
  ".+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
  ".+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
```

Tried adding jsonTransform, but that does not work either-

```
"transform": {
  ".+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
  ".+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  ".+\.json$": "/config/jest/jsonTransform.js",
  "(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
```

jsonTransform.js ->

```
module.exports = {
    process(src) {
        return {
            code: module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(src))};,
        };
    },
};
```

Node: 16.15.1
npm: 8.12.2
jest: 28.1.2
@testing-library/react: 12.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix!!! Wrong regex. Missed ^ in fileTransform

```
"transform": {
  ".+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
  ".+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
```